# comparison of derivatives

Tags: functions, inequality, differential

I have a basic question related to inequalities:

Suppose that $A(x) \leq B(x) $ in $[a, b]$.

Then under what hypotheses 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} A(x) \leq \frac{d}{dx} B(x)  
$$ 
in $[a, b]$?

So far I am thinking about monotonicity of both A and B in $[a,b]$.
I would like to know all of the implicit hypotheses if I use the statement in a proof.

Comment: The fact that $A(x) \le B(x)$ doesn't tell you anything at all about their derivatives: just translate $A$ upwards, and you get $A(x)+d \ge B(x)$ for some constant $d$ (you can do this since $[a,b]$ is compact and the two maps are, I assume, differentiable, hence in particular continuous, so that they attain their maxima on $[a,b]$). Then you have inverted the situation, but the derivatives are still the same. So you can't conclude anything.

Comment: investigate the function f(x):=B(x)-A(x), you have $$0\le f(x) \tag{1}$$ $$0 \le \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \tag{2}$$. What does $(2)$ tell you?

Comment: This implies increasing function. But as I asked: are there other implicit hypotheses?

Answer (score 1):

not always true. for example, consider $A = x $ and $B= x^2$. We know $A(x) \geq B(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, but, $A' = 1 $ and $B' = 2x $ and

$$ 1 \geq 2x \; \; \; \text{does  not hold for all} \; \; x \in [0,1] $$